# PHP regex output converting

Tags: php, regex, time

I want to  turn a output like 12h 34m 45s to 12:34:45

also it should be possible if one o these is returned empty is will ignore it.
So 34m 45s should be 00:34:45 and off course single digits should bee possible like 1h 4m 1s and a combo off single and double digits like 12h 4m 12s and so on.

Can someone please help ?

This is the actual code

`$van = $_POST['gespreksduur_van'];
        $tot = $_POST['gespreksduur_tot'];
        $regex = '/(\d\d?h ?)?(\d\d?m ?)?(\d\d?s)?/';`

```
        if(preg_match($regex, $van, $match) AND preg_match($regex, $tot, $matches))
        {
            for ($n = 1; $n <= 3; ++$n) { if (!array_key_exists($n, $match)) $match[$n] = 0; }
            for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; ++$i) { if (!array_key_exists($i, $matches)) $matches[$i] = 0; }

            $van = printf("%02d:%02d:%02d", $matches[1], $matches[2], $matches[3]);
            $tot = printf("%02d:%02d:%02d", $match[1], $match[2], $match[3]);

            print($van);
            print($tot);

            $data['gespreksduurvan'] = htmlspecialchars($van);
            $data['gespreksduurtot'] = htmlspecialchars($tot);

            $smarty->assign('gsv',$data['gespreksduurvan']);
            $smarty->assign('gst',$data['gespreksduurtot']);
        }
```

Comment: None of the provided answers except mine are working for this string `1h 45m`. Maybe someone can update their regex answer so that this string passes too.

Comment: @danishgoel, my updated answer works. In my original, I just forgot a question mark in the regex, accidentally making seconds required. Now it's working

Comment: define *empty*, is `hms` acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex to extract the components, and then a `printf()` to format the components how you like:

```
$time = "1h 45m";
preg_match("/(\d\d?h ?)?(\d\d?m ?)?(\d\d?s)?/", $time, $matches);
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; ++$i) { if (!array_key_exists($i, $matches)) $matches[$i] = 0; }
printf("%02d:%02d:%02d", $matches[1], $matches[2], $matches[3]);
```

The regex allows optional components. The for loop there just fills any missing keys with a default value of zero (to prevent undefined key errors when seconds, or both minutes/seconds are missing). The printf always prints all components with two zeros.

Comment: sorry if this is a stupid question but can you just print $out ?

Comment: I updated it to use `printf` instead of `sprintf`. That outputs it immeidately.

Comment: But for reference, you can always do `echo $out;` to display something.

Comment: Thank you youre answer worked. Maybe the rest did also but this is very simple to understand for me.

Comment: @user769498, please see my updated answer. In my old one, I accidentally made the seconds field required.

Comment: i get the right output but somehow it adds to number 8's at the back ? so the output is 01:46:00 01:45:0088  Can someone explain why ?

Comment: @user769498, show your actual code. I bet it is something after the printf() here that is displaying the "88".

Comment: i have added the code to the original question but its kinda weird cause i copy pasted it

Comment: if this helps the 8 also appear in the input boxes after submit button is pessed

Comment: @user769498, that code by itself should not print `88`. In any case, I'm certain the `88` is not coming from the code in this answer. It must be even *after* the code you posted.

Comment: i fixed it and it works now the double 8 came from
 print($van);
 print($tot);
in combo with printf i changed it to sprintf and it worked.
could you plz explain to me why you use 'for' statement what they do and why ?

Comment: i just saw the explanation. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regex, you can use [preg_replace_callback](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

```
    <?php


function callback($matches)
{   
    var_dump($matches);
    if ($matches[2] == "") $matches[2] = "00";
    if ($matches[4] == "") $matches[4] = "00";
    if ($matches[6] == "") $matches[6] = "00";
    return $matches[2] . ":" . $matches[4] . ":" . $matches[6];
}   

$str = "12h 34m 45s";
$str = preg_replace_callback("`(([0-2]?[0-9])h )?(([0-5]?[0-9])m )?(([0-5]?[0-9])s)?`", "callback", $str, 1); 

echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how you can do this without regex

```
// function for your purpose
function to_time($str){
    $time_arr = explode(' ', $str);
    $time_h = '00';
    $time_m = '00';
    $time_s = '00';
    foreach($time_arr as $v){
        switch(substr($v, -1)){
            case 'h': $time_h = intval($v); break;
            case 'm': $time_m = intval($v); break;
            case 's': $time_s = intval($v); break;
        }
    }
    return $time_h . ':' . $time_m . ':' . $time_s;
}

//test array
$time[] = '1h 45s';
$time[] = '12h 35m 45s';
$time[] = '1m 45s';

// output
foreach($time as $t)
    var_dump(to_time($t));
```

This outputs

```
string '1:00:45' (length=7)
string '12:35:45' (length=8)
string '00:1:45' (length=7)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "12h 34m 45s";
$string = str_replace(array("h","m","s"), array(":",":",""), str_replace(" ", "", $string));

echo $string;
```

Something like this?